# socket.emit() not working inside a function in a react app

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, express, socket.io

My socket backend is working fine, I have tested it through postman. The problem is socket.emit is working inside useEffect but not working inside the function sendMessageHandler.

Following is my server code:

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";
import { server } from "./app";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { Message } from "./types/message.types";
import deleteUserFromSocketList from "./utils/lib/deleteUserFromSocketList";

dotenv.config();

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: process.env.CLIENT_URL,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    credentials: true,
  },
});

interface User {
  name: string;
  email: string;
  uid: string;
  sid: string;
}

var connectedUsers: User[] = [];

io.use((socket, next) => {
  //TODO verify user request
  //TODO save or replace user socket id to database
  next();
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  io.to(socket.id).emit("user-sid", { sid: socket.id })

  socket.on("user-details", (user) => {
    connectedUsers = deleteUserFromSocketList(connectedUsers, user);
    connectedUsers.push(user);
    console.log(`user joined: ${socket.id}`);
    io.emit("user-joined", connectedUsers);
  });

  socket.on("send-message", (msg) => {
    // if (msg.receipient.sid.length === 0) return;
    socket.to(msg.receipient.sid).emit("receive-message", msg);
    console.log(msg);
    console.log("message delivered");
  });

  socket.on("disconnect-user", () => {
    const updatedUserList: User[] = [];
    connectedUsers.forEach((user) => {
      if (user.sid !== socket.id) updatedUserList.push(user);
    });
    connectedUsers = updatedUserList
    // socket.disconnect()
    io.emit("user-left", connectedUsers);
  });
});

export { io };
```

And the client side code is following:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getCookie } from "../../utils";
import UsersList from "./userBar";
import CommunicationPanel from "./chatPanel";
import { Message } from "../../types/Message.types";
import { getAllCookies } from "../../utils/getCookie";
import { User } from "../../types/User.types";
import createMessage from "../../utils/createMessage";
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const URL = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL || "";

const socket = io(URL, {
  withCredentials: true,
  retries: 5,
  reconnectionDelay: 5000,
  reconnectionAttempts: 3,
  autoConnect: true
});

export default function Dashboard() {

  const [isInitial, setInitial] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [currSid, setCurrSid] = useState<string>("");
  const [activeChat, setActiveChat] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [messageList, setMessageList] = useState<Message[]>([]);
  const [onlineUsers, setOnlineUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);


  if (getCookie("isUserLoggedIn") !== "true") {
    window.location.replace("/");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    function notifyUserConnected() {
      socket.on("user-sid", (connData) => {
        const sid: string = connData.sid;
        setCurrSid(sid);
        const { name, email, uid } = getAllCookies();
        const user = { name, email, uid, sid };
        socket.emit("user-details", user);
      });
    }

    function updateUserList(userList: User[]) {
      setOnlineUsers(userList);
    }

    function updateMessageList(msg: Message) {
      setMessageList((list) => {
        return [...list, msg];
      });
    }

    socket.on("connect", notifyUserConnected);
    socket.on("user-joined", (list) => updateUserList(list));
    socket.on("user-left", (list) => updateUserList(list));
    socket.on("receive-message", (msg) => updateMessageList(msg));

    return () => {
      socket.off("user-joined");
      socket.off("user-left");
      socket.off("user-sid");
      socket.off("receive-message");
      socket.emit("disconnect-user");
    };
  }, []);


  const sendMessageHandler = (msg: string) => {
    const message: Message = createMessage(msg, activeChat, currSid);
    socket.connect()
    socket.emit("send-message", message);
  };

  return (
    <div className="md:flex justify-center items-start w-[100%] h-[85vh] overflow-hidden">
      <UsersList
        users={onlineUsers.filter((user) => user.sid !== currSid)}
        setActiveChat={(args: User) => {
          setActiveChat(args);
          setInitial(false);
        }}
      />
      {currSid}
      <CommunicationPanel
        messageList={messageList}
        sendMessageHandler={sendMessageHandler}
        chatData={activeChat}
        isInitial={isInitial}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried logging and checking the program flow but it seems that somehow the "socket.emit("send-message", message)" is not executing. The log command before and after the same statement is executing. Please help

Comment: Might have to do something with `socket.connect()`. Looks like `autoConnect` is already on so you don't need this. If that's not a solution, consider adding error handling.  I don't see any code that suggests that you are handling errors and this is important for this kind of use-case.

Comment: I have tried wrapping up my code in try catch block, but it does not throw any error.